# Reinstall files after upgrading OS?

Tags: macos

Upgrading from 10.5.8 to 10.6.3

As I understand I need to back up my files. Is this a precautionary measure or do I necessarily have to reinstall all my files after upgrading the os?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always wise to have backups of your stuff, not just for when you upgrade, but always if you have even a single document of photo that you do not want to lose.

Advise to backup is a common precaution before attempting any major upgrade, either to an application or to the whole Operating System.  Whilst any upgrade failure is unlikely to harm your data, it could result in (rare cases) a system that you cannot boot, which effectively leaves you unable to access your data even though it's still actually perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a precautionary measure, for the case if something goes wrong. If the update runs w/o any troubles (which should be the case) you don't need to reinstall all your files.

I've just configured time machine before updating my mac, and in that way you are on the safe side.